# Why are there ropes on fingerboards?

Tags: gear, rock-climbing

I picked up a couple fingerboards from the pro shop, and hung them on the rafters in our basement. However, I have no idea what the ropes are for, unless someone might tie the boards to a tree. What are they for?

[image]

For reference: The manufacturer provides [this guide](http://www.metoliusclimbing.com/training_giude_rock_ring.html) for training with this kind of board.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It all depends on how you want to mount your rock rings. I mounted mine like this from a door-jam pull-up bar:

[image: Rock Rings hanging from Pull-Up bar]

Though you could mount them like monkey bars, or any other way:

[image: Rock Ring monkey bars]

The idea, from a training perspective, is that if the rock rings are hanging from rope you have to expend more effort with your core to keep your body from swinging. And building core strength is important in climbing.

Comment: I hadn't thought about hanging them suspended like that.

Comment: After I started using the rock rings instead of mounted pull-up bars or fingerboards, my core strength got a serious boost. It has made a noticeable difference in my climbing.  Have fun!

Comment: The first time I saw fingerboards they were hanging like this second picture, not for "monkey bars" just for pull-ups, but yeah, they require different muscles to stabilize them.